# Three.js directional light shadow not working if object small

Tags: three.js, shadow, light

I am making an example of using light shadow. It works well, for example:

```
// Create cube and add to scene.
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.y += 0.1;
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/curisiro/gxby5kes/15/)

However, when I reduce dimension of box from 0.1 to 0.01, the shadow disappears:

```
// Create cube and add to scene.
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.y += 0.01;
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/curisiro/3gra94t6/6/)

Can you tell me how can get shadow with small object?

Thank you.

Comment: Tip: add this helper to your scene: `const shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper( directionalLight.shadow.camera );` You will see you need to reduce the size of your shadow camera frustum.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you. I found out that I have to increase shadow mapSize in order to see the shadow of small object.

Comment: Likely better, decrease the shadow frustum size. `light.shadow.camera.left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`.